# Entropy of noncentral multivariate t distribution

Tags: entropy, t-distribution

I am looking at calculating the entropy of a multivariate noncentral t-distribution.

I found in the central case (mean is zero) the entropy is the same as multivariate normal with a correction for degrees of freedom (ie only depends on covariance and $\nu$). But in the noncentral case the extra term is a more complicated infinite sum which depends both on $\mu^T \mathbf{R}^{-1} \mu$ and $\nu$.

I guess I was just trying to gain some intuition as to why the entropy would depend on the mean $\mu$. If the distribution is shifted around in space the entropy (which is the integral over the whole thing) should stay the same (as with the normal)?

The expression I have for the entropy is (from *Multivariate t Distributions and Their Applications*, Kotz and Nadarajah):

$$
H = \frac{1}{2}\log|R| + \log \left[ \frac{(\nu \pi)^{p/2}}{\Gamma(p/2)} B \left(\frac{p}{2},\frac{\nu}{2}\right) \right] + \frac{\nu + p}{2}M(\nu,p,\Delta)
$$

where $\Delta=\mu^T R^{-1}\mu$ and

$$
M(\nu,p,\Delta) = \exp\left(-\frac{\Delta}{2}\right)\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{j!}\left\{ \psi\left( \frac{\nu+p+2j}{2}\right) - \psi\left(\frac{\nu}{2}\right) \right\}
$$

A second part of the question would be for any practical tips for calculating this quantity (are there any approximations or tricks for the infinite sum)?

Comment: The noncentral t is not a location family.  It is [usually defined as a ratio of two random variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_t-distribution) and only the numerator is shifted by $\mu$.  That's why the entropy depends on $\mu$. It would be a good idea to plot a few PDFs of this family so you can improve your understanding of it.

Comment: Thanks - I think I was confused - I am using "t location scale" distribution in Matlab - I guess this is location shifted but central. If I need only symmetric (central) distributions then it should be OK just to use the central entropy expression with the t location scale fit and ignore the location? (Since the entropy of a central T should not depend on the location?)

Comment: Your are correct that the entropy of a location family will not depend on the location.